# How to debug Rust in Intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, gdb

I have searched for rust debugging and found guides for vs code only. My question is how to configure intellij rust for debugging?

Comment: There is the issue with instructions: https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/535

Comment: It seems that intellij-rust (for "ultimate" only) has added initial support for this: https://intellij-rust.github.io/2020/04/27/changelog-121.html

Comment: move to VSCode . as idea not support this and sucks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot debug Rust in IntelliJ, but CLion supports debugging. However CLion is not free.

Comment: Thank you, TobiP64.  I just updated my Intellij ultimate and my CLion tools and confirm @TobiP64's answer.  CLion provides some very nice debugging features for Rust.  I have been using VSCode, which is excellent, but might be using CLion in the future.  And, yes...it does require purchase of a license.

Comment: Small note, if you are a student with a university email then you can get a 1 year subscription for free and continue to renew it as long as you have access to that email.

Answer (score 22):

Old question, but great news! https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/05/whats-new-in-intellij-rust/
Now it's VERY easy to debug Rust in IntelliJ, just download mentioned plugin and the rest is done before first usage.

Comment: yes, now they support debugging in Intellij idea ultimate version, but not in community version yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes... However, it's still better than getting even another IDE :-)

Comment: anyway evaluate doesn't work - "error: no field named ..." on any expression

Comment: meanwhile debugging in Visual Studio code is free, sucks having to use Visual Studio code for something that's free with every other language.

Don't be petty Jetbrainz, stop pushing developers away to the competition.

Answer (score 0):

Current Ultimate IntelliJ does not seem to support Rust debugging beyond primitive types. You can setup breakpoints and step through but you can NOT really examine any values from objects. Big disappointment. I may move to VSCode - unless JetBrains will give me a discount on CLion.